# recordtype controlling picklist values inline edit issue on rerender

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have been facing issue in using inlineEdit on vf page.
On page load picklist showing values in respect to recordtype of the record but when i am rerender section it starts showing all values here is the sample code.

```
<apex:page standardController="case__c" extensions="inlineEditCaseController" id="pg">
  <apex:form id="frm">
    <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton value="test" immediate="true" reRender="test" />
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      <apex:outputPanel id="test">
        <apex:outputField value="{!case__c.picklist__c}">
          <apex:inlineEditSupport />
        </apex:outputField>
      </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

here `case__c` is custom object on which i have 2 recordtypes test1 & test2 `picklist__c` field has following mapping with recordtype.

```
Recordtype  Picklist__c
test1       A,B,C
test2       D,E,F
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a bug. I was able to replicate your issue by doing the following:
1. Added test1 and test2 record types to Cases
2. Split the Picklist values for the Case Type field
3. Added the following visualforce page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case">
  <apex:form id="frm">
    <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton value="test" immediate="true" reRender="test" />
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      <apex:outputPanel id="test">
        <apex:outputField value="{!Case.Type}">
          <apex:inlineEditSupport />
        </apex:outputField>
      </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

4. Loaded page with an existing case that has the test1 recordType assigned.
5. Double clicked the Type field and see the following limited values as expected:
[image: correct]
6. Clicked the "test" button to rerender the output panel
7. Double clicked the Type field again and now see all values
[image]
I was able to find other inline edit issues in known cases, [here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008YniAAE) and [here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008YBOAA2), but not this specific issue. I would recommend opening a case with Salesforce.

Comment: I just noticed this too, on a page that previously was honoring the Record Types' different picklist item values before the Winter '16 update.

Comment: I found that if I have the picklist fields set to required="true" that the re-render fails to update the items but if I have it set to required="false" the re-render does work although the re-render seems to happen onfocus (not coded, but by exposing picklist values with dropdown toggle) instead of onchange (tied to RecordType inputField with actionsupport)